# The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance

Tags: solidity, remix

When I call changeScore, I get an error
[enter image description here][1]

The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.

Code

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


// Student
contract Score{
    address public teacher;
    mapping (address => uint) StudentScore;


    modifier onlyTeacher(){
        require(msg.sender == teacher,"Don't Change Score");
        _;
    }

    function addTeacher(address _address) public{
        teacher = _address;
    }

    // external
    function IScore(address _account,uint _score) public onlyTeacher{
        require(_score <= 100,"Score more then 100");
        StudentScore[_account] = _score;
    }

    function getStudentScore(address _address) public view returns (uint){
        return StudentScore[_address];
    }
}

interface IScoreService{
    function IScore(address _account, uint _score) external;
}

// Teacher 
contract Teacher{
    address public selfAddress;

    IScoreService public score;

    constructor(){
        selfAddress = address(this);
    }
    
    function changeScore(address _account, uint _score) public {
        score.IScore(_account, _score);
    }

}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwWHz.png
```

Answer (score 0):

The `IScore()` function has a `onlyTeacher` modifier, effectively allowing the function to be executed only from the `teacher` address.

Mind that the address executing the function is the `Teacher` contract address in this case.

Solution: Set the `Teacher` contract address as the `teacher` variable by executing the `addTeacher()` function (passing it the `Teacher` contract address) on the `Score` contract. Then you'll be able to execute the `IScore()` function through the `Teacher` contract.